# 'Bouchée' et 'gorgée'

Tags: synonymes, nuance

'Bouchée' et 'gorgée' ont un sens et une formation similaires, mais le premier est uniquement pour la nourriture et le second pour les liquides. Y a-t-il une raison spécifique à la différence d'emploi entre 'bouchée' et 'gorgée' ? L'inverse ou de purs synonymes seraient tout aussi plausibles a priori. On peut noter que l'anglais *mouthful*, correspondant précisément à 'bouchée', s'utilise aussi bien pour les liquides que pour la nourriture.

Answer (score 3):

C'est une question de bon sens il me semble : ce qui est solide va remplir la bouche pendant un certain instant, pendant que l'on mâche ; ce qui est liquide va se trouver dans la gorge sitôt introduit dans la bouche.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99390/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-bouchee-et-gorgee).

Answer (score 3):

On emploie le mot 'bouchée' pour les aliments car les aliments sont en premier lieu "travaillés" dans la bouche par la mastication.

On emploie le mot 'gorgée' pour les liquides car aucune action n'est effectuée par la bouche sur les liquides. Ils passent directement dans la gorge avec la déglutition.

Comment: C'est à peu près la réponse de LPH, non ? On notera aussi que l'anglais _mouthful_ fonctionne complètement différemment.

Comment: @MathieuBouville > Entièrement d'accord, ceci ressemble très fort à la réponse de LPH. Autre formulation mais cette réponse n'apporte rien de plus ou de moins. Pour la peine j'ai upvoté celle de LPH et pas celle-ci pour ne pas encourager les perroquets...